# Job id from DATAVIEW_SENT does not exists in DATAVIEW_JOB Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I need to report the number of email sent by subscriber.

I use the bellow query to search all sent

I get a job id for a mail sent via email studio but when I request the job by id in DATAVIEW_JOB there is no result.

Job ID for the sent is very greater than last job id.

Any idea

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT 
P.SubscriberKey,
P.SubscriberID,
P.OYBAccountID,
P.EventDate,
P.JobID,
P.TriggeredSendCustomerKey,
P.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
P.AccountID,
P.BatchID,
P.ListID
FROM DATAVIEW_SENT P
WHERE P.[EventDate] > '2020-10-15'
```

Comment: `DATAVIEW_SENT` and `DATAVIEW_JOB` are not the actual names of the data views.  Those are `_Sent` and `_Job`  You've got some process populating those data extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Is the missing JobID a triggered send?  If so, JobIDs for Triggers (and Journey sends) do not change unless the definition is republished.  So if the missing JobID in your scenario hasn't been republished in the last 6 months, then I wouldn't expect it to be there.

You can retrieve aggregated send data for your entire account history using the method I describe [**here**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-storing-aggregated-send-data/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The mail has been sent in email studio without any trigger. It's just a simple send. I will use your method and verify if It can helps me.

Comment: I found why I had this issue for info. It's because DATAVIEW_SENT is not _sent dat view. It's a temporary data extension made by our vendor that has not been refreshed for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

_Job Data View ([Official Docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_job.htm&type=5), [My SFMC Docs](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/config/sfmc-config-system-data-views#_job)) is unique, as it is limited to a single Business Unit.

Your parent Business Unit has access to _Sent, _Open, _Click and other data from all Business Units, but this is not the case with _Job.

You can query only those jobs that occurred in the Business Unit where you execute your SQL snippet.